# How to run a script after another one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a browser resize script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        if ($(this).height() <= 800) {
            $('.content').css('max-height', '500px'); //set max height
        } 
        else {
            $('.content').css('max-height', ''); //delete attribute
        }
    }).resize()
})
```

I want to make the jscrollpane run after the window resizes because that is when I will need the scrollbar.  At the current code I have it just shows the regular scrollbar.

```
$(function() {
    $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
});
```

Is there a way to run this script after the max height script is completed?

Comment: Why not just stick `$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();` at the end of your window resize function? Or make the scroll pane function non-anonymous and call it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

   $(window).on('resize', function(){
     if ($(this).height() <= 800){
      $('.content').css('max-height', '500px'); //set max height
     } else{
      $('.content').css('max-height', ''); //delete attribute
   }

   $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane(); //why not call it here?

 }).resize()
})
</script>
```

Comment: It must have a major issue with using max-height because it still display a regular scrollbar even with the code you provided.

Comment: It looks like it does have problems with `max-height`, I found this on a Google search: http://code.google.com/p/jscrollpane/issues/detail?id=182 The bug is reproduced here: http://sandbox.saeidmohadjer.com/jscrollpanetest.html#

Comment: Yes I just seen that.  How do you use the api destroy?

Answer (score 0):

You're just calling a method here:

```
$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
```

..JavaScript is perfectly capable of doing more things than just one within a single script block. You don't have to regard each action as a separate script.

So just put your method-call within the resize-event-handler, such as:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    if ($(this).height() <= 800){
        $('.content').css('max-height', '500px'); //set max height
    } else{
      $('.content').css('max-height', ''); //delete attribute
    }

    $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane(); // just call it here!
}
```

..and you're done.

It might be useful to read some articles about JavaScript. Or some books.

Some nice starting points:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp
http://www.codecademy.com/

Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you for your input.  I do need to read up on js.  I will take a look at your links.

Comment: It must have a major issue with using max-height because it still display a regular scrollbar even with the code you provided.

Comment: I did however find this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456293/jscrollpane-does-not-support-css-max-height  but I don't know how to destroy and reapply it.